# Angular router-outlet unsubscribe

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I want to ask i my way o thinking is correct as i found few solutions on stack and not sure if i get i correct. So i want to emit value form child to parent using router-outlet. Question is i am correctly unsubscribing?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  totalItems: number;
  currentCount$: Observable<number>;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public accountService: AccountService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.subscription)
  }
  onActivate(component) {
    if (component instanceof MemberGridComponent) {
      this.subscription = component.itemCount.subscribe((c) => {
        this.currentCount$ = c;
      });
    }
  }
  onDeactivate() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
  logout() {
    this.accountService.logout();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
}
```

Router

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)" (deactivate)="onDeactivate()"></router-outlet>
```

HTML

```
  <ul>
      <li routerLink="/home/a" routerLinkActive="active" style="padding-right: 30px;"><span>a</span> <span >{{currentCount$}}</span> </li>
      <li routerLink="/home/b" routerLinkActive="active">b</li>
      <li routerLink="/home/c" routerLinkActive="active">c</li>
      <li>Help</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: It looks correct. Does it work?

Comment: yes works main concern if it is crrect